# Dotfuscator throwing error on Xamarin.Android project

Tags: xamarin.android, dotfuscator

I followed the steps to integrate Dotfuscator into my Xamarin.Android project as described [here](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html), but when it's time to build the project, I'm getting the following error:

> The "_DotfuscatorXamarin_DetermineDefaultInputsTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   2>\path\to\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets(570,5): error MSB4018: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   2>\path\to\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets(570,5): error MSB4018:    at InlineCode._DotfuscatorXamarin_DetermineDefaultInputsTask.Execute() in \path\to\AppData\Local\Temp\eruovv3u.0.cs:line 106
>   2>\path\to\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets(570,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   2>\path\to\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets(570,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

I have looked and looked online, but no one seems to be having this issue. I think the problem has something to do with generating the default configuration file on the first build. Any ideas?

Comment: I work for PreEmptive, and to best assess the problem I have two questions: (1) What version of the targets file are you using? The first comment in the file will list its version; the latest is 1.1.0. (2) Are you referencing any .NET Standard (or .NET Core) libraries?

Comment: @JoeSewell (1) The first comment in the targets file states: "Dotfuscator-Xamarin integration file for MSBuild Version 1.1.0". So I'm assuming I'm using the latest version. (2) Also, the Xamarin.Android project references a .NET Standard 1.4 class library project in the same solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This issue has been fixed in newer versions of Dotfuscator. See the detailed instructions for the free [*Dotfuscator Community*](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/getting_started_xamarin.html) and for the commercially-licensed [*Dotfuscator Professional*](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html). The original answer follows below.

---

*Full Disclosure*: I am a developer of Dotfuscator at PreEmptive Solutions, and am answering this question in that role.

You're right, the problem is the default config file generation in the targets file (`PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets`) - sorry about that. Specifically, the build integration is attempting to discover project references, but expects the classic MSBuild project format, not the new minimal one used by .NET Standard.

You can work around this issue as follows:

1. In the targets file, locate the `_DotfuscatorXamarinConfigTemplateLines` property and copy its value (within the CDATA section) to a new file named `DotfuscatorConfig.xml` (or whatever value you supplied for the `DotfuscatorXamarinConfigFileName` property in your project file) in the same directory as your project file.
2. In Visual Studio, build your project once in a configuration you want to protect (e.g., *AnyCPU|Release*). It will error, because the new config file doesn't have any input assemblies yet, but by building now we get those assemblies in the right location for configuring Dotfuscator.
3. Open Dotfuscator's user interface.

   - For Community Edition, from Visual Studio, open the Tools menu and select PreEmptive Protection - Dotfuscator.
   - For Professional Edition, run Dotfuscator Professional Edition from the Start Menu.
4. In the user interface, *File | Open* the file created in step 1.
5. On the Inputs screen, click the "Add Input" button (a green plus-sign in Community Edition, a folder-opening icon in Professional Edition).
6. Browse to your project directory, then `obj\Release\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin`, and then select the assemblies you want to protect.

   - Substitute `Release` with the appropriate directory for the configuration you built in step 2.
   - You should select assemblies that correspond to projects in your solution, and not select third-party and assemblies that are part of the framework.
7. Save the config file.
8. Navigate to the Project Properties editor.

   - In Community Edition, go to the *Build Settings* screen and select the *Project Properties* tab.
   - In Professional Edition, go to the *Settings* tab and select the *Settings > Project Properties* screen.
9. Add the following project properties (instructions [for Community Edition](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/gui_buildsettings.html#pctoc-project-properties-tab), and [for Professional Edition](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/gui_standalone.html#pctoc-project-properties)):

   - Property name `InDir`, value `obj\Release\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin`
   - Property name `OutDir`, value `obj\Release\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfout`
   - Property name `ReportDir`, value `DotfuscatorReports\Release`
   - Substitute `Release` with the appropriate directory for the configuration you built in step 2. Note that the directories pointed to by `OutDir` and `ReportDir` won't exist on-disk yet.
10. Save the config file.
11. Return to the Inputs screen and select an input and click the pencil icon. Edit the path to the assembly from an absolute path to `${configdir}\${InDir}\AssemblyName.dll`, substituting `AssemblyName.dll` for the actual name and extension of the assembly. Repeat for each input assembly.
12. Save the config file (and commit it to source control).
13. Rebuild the project in Visual Studio. The build integration will use your config file instead of trying to generate a new one.

Comment: This did it. Thank you for the detailed instructions.

Comment: @user6675963 I believe he was referring to an older version of the Dotfuscator user interface. The properties section is actually not a tab, it's actually on the left panel right under the "Inputs" item.

Comment: @Joe Sewell, you are master. It works as expected.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

on top of the Joe's marvelous solution I ended up changing one value from true to false with regards to the instructions on https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html#pctoc-setup
to get my android solution to build/run.

```
    <DotfuscatorXamarinGenerateNewConfigFile>false</DotfuscatorXamarinGenerateNewConfigFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been configuring the Dotfuscator Community Edition at Xamarin.Android project according to [this user guide](https://blog.xamarin.com/protecting-xamarin-apps-dotfuscator/). And I also had the following build error (pretty the same as @AxiomaticNexus):

```
    Error       The "_DotfuscatorXamarin_DetermineDefaultInputsTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at InlineCode._DotfuscatorXamarin_DetermineDefaultInputsTask.Execute() in c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\wqhfhbsk.0.cs:line 106
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() eKey.Droid  C:\VSProjects\dotFuscatorTest\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets    570
```

I've fixed this issue using @Joe Sewell's **Full Disclosure**.
I hope **PreEmptive Solutions** will realese the fixed version asap!!!

Answer (score 0):

At some point I was missing the file *PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets* in the root of project. I already executed the instructions above described by Joe Sewell, but later noticed the missing file.

Error were like this:

```
    Error       The "_DotfuscatorXamarin_DetermineDefaultInputsTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at InlineCode._DotfuscatorXamarin_DetermineD  efaultInputsTask.Execute() in c:\Users\hieta\AppData\Local\Temp\k3a5f2bj.0.cs:line 106
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() WorkSafe.Droid
```

Just FYI if anyone else could avoid waste of time.