# Xamarin.Android code obfuscation

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, deobfuscation, dotfuscator

I am working on a project in which I need to add Obfuscation.

I have reviewed this [link](https://blog.xamarin.com/protecting-xamarin-apps-dotfuscator/), but am getting an exception.

please suggest what is the best way to obfuscate a Xamarin form application.

```
Exception : Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "_DotfuscatorXamarin_DetermineDefaultInputsTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at InlineCode._DotfuscatorXamarin_DetermineDefaultInputsTask.Execute() in c:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\y5if5f14.0.cs:line 106
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Demo.Android    E:\xxx\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets   570
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dotfuscator throwing error on Xamarin.Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535531/dotfuscator-throwing-error-on-xamarin-android-project)

Comment: @JoeSewell,  Thanks for the above link , I have gone through it but still the marked answer there did not work for me.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose the issue without more details. If you're using Professional Edition (including evaluations), then you can [contact PreEmptive support](https://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support/). Otherwise, please add more information to your question, such as what kinds of projects your Xamarin.Android project references. (*Note*: I work for PreEmptive and am responding to this question as part of my job.)