# Having problems with Dotfuscator

Tags: c#, xamarin, dotfuscator

I'm having the same problem as descripted in
[Dotfuscator throwing error on Xamarin.Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535531/dotfuscator-throwing-error-on-xamarin-android-project) but the proceeds doesn't work for me. Is there  something else that I can do? I'm using community edition.

Comment: Doesn't ProGuard do the same/similar thing? (I am using it on my Xamarin project without any issues).

Comment: In my case, i would like to use for obfuscation and in my understand this is a feature only for native android development; it's not suported for xamarin. Am i wrong?

Comment: @WesleyLopes You are correct that [Xamarin does not use ProGuard for obfuscation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=vswin#proguard-in-xamarinandroid). I work on the Dotfuscator team; could you add more detail to your question? What kind of projects does your Xamarin.Android project reference? Is the error the exact one in the linked answer? You've marked your question "sql" - is there something specific to SQL that you are running into?

Comment: @JoeSowell, the erro is exactly the same linked; it was not working because i made a mistake on first step. That's why it was not working, but it's ok now. It was my fault.

Comment: @WesleyLopes OK, I'm glad you were able to resolve your issue.